# can an Android service running on its own process access the app's /data/data/<package> folder?

Tags: android, native

Part of my application, I create an Android Service, which encapsulate a Native code library.  The Android Service is running in its own process.
I need the Native code from the Android service to access and write in the private data from the installation folder (/data/data/package folder).
Is that possible?
Looks like the native code is getting a Write Access error.

In the same line, can this Service access the SD Card directory at "/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/ ?
It looks also that the native code gets an access error.

Any confirmation will help

thanks
eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For both questions: Yes.

Your Service is part of your application, same process as Activities and other parts of app. It can access app's private folder, correctly determined by:

```
getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.example.app", 0).applicationInfo.dataDir;
```

Also it can write to SD card, assuming you have permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

You probably wrongly assume that your service runs in different process than rest of app. It's still the same process, native code doesn't make difference.

Comment: the reason why I said my Android Service was running in a different process is because I specificy it in the Manifest: <service android:name="com.example.app.service  android:process="com.example.app.Service">

Also, how would you access it from the Native code (C/C++)?

Comment: Ok then, another process seems to be possible. Don't know if it has effect on access rights, most likely not.
But why do you put it into another process?